# Converting relationships between data inside a JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have got a function that produces an array that is made up of X amount of sub-arrays containing Y amount of objects. Both of these factors are passed to a function to produce an array that looks something like this:

```
[
  [ { '0': 3 }, { '1': 4 }, { '2': 6 }, 'Estimate:': '0jvyt8a' ],
  [ { '0': 4 }, { '1': 6 }, { '2': 3 }, 'Estimate:': 'mc973fs' ],
  [ { '0': 4 }, { '1': 1 }, { '2': 3 }, 'Estimate:': 'vwsfh8k' ],
  [ { '0': 4 }, { '1': 3 }, { '2': 5 }, 'Estimate:': 'n6xzge3' ],
  [ { '0': 8 }, { '1': 7 }, { '2': 1 }, 'Estimate:': 'v0jn7bh' ]
]
```

My question is, is there a way I can convert this array from this structure. To a structure shown below:

```
[
    [1,{1: "vwsfh8k"}, {2: "v0jn7bh"}]
    [3,{1: "0jvyt8a"}, {2: "mc973fs"}, {3:"vwsfh8k"}, {4:"n6xzge3"}]
]
```

Basically, my aim is to take the original array generated by the script (see below) and pass it through another function to record how many times each number was present and what it's 'estimate' number was.

In this example, I just created random numbers between 0 and 10 so an option would be to iterate and count each value I guess but unfortunately, I can't do this because eventually I will be using 5-letter combinations instead of numbers but numbers were easiest to show for an example and proof of concept.

So, I guess, I need to get an array of each unique value and then look at each value up in the original array to find out what estimate IDs have it present. Unfortunately, I don't have even an idea of where, to begin with, this, so I was hoping you guys can help.

Code to generate random array:

```
// Making an empty array
const arr = [];

//Generating the estimate IDs and placing them all in their own object in their own array.
function estimateGen(length, nodes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)    {
        const estimate = [];
        let estimateVal = Math.random().toString(36).replace('0.','').slice(0,7);
        estimate[`Estimate:`] = estimateVal;
        arr.push(estimate);
        nodeGen(estimate, nodes)
    }
}

// Adding x amount of nodes between 1 and 10 into each estimate sub-array in their own objects.
function nodeGen(estimate, nodes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
        const node = {};
        let nodeID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        node[i] = nodeID;
        estimate.push(node);

    }
}

// Calling the function and saying how many nodes per estimate we want.
estimateGen(5, 3);
console.log(arr);
```

If you have any suggestions on how to improve this code or as to why the estimate values in the sub-array are always last in the array that would be very helpful.

Thank you

--- EDIT ---

I have changed the code that generates the original array to produce a simpler array.

```
// Making an empty array
const arr = [];

//Generating the estimate IDs and placing them all in their own object in their own array.
function estimateGen(length, nodes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)    {
        const estimate = [];
        let estimateVal = Math.random().toString(36).replace('0.','').slice(0,7);
        estimate.push(estimateVal);
        arr.push(estimate);
        nodeGen(estimate, nodes)
    }
}

// Adding x amount of nodes between 1 and 10 into each estimate sub array in their own objects.
function nodeGen(estimate, nodes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
        let nodeID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        estimate.push(nodeID);

    }
}

// Calling the function and saying how many nodes per estimate we want.
estimateGen(5, 3);
console.log(arr);
```

From this code I now get the result:

```
[
  [ 'p68xw8h', 5, 4, 6 ],
  [ 'wn2yoee', 5, 4, 5 ],
  [ '1w01tem', 9, 7, 4 ],
  [ 'we3s53f', 8, 8, 8 ],
  [ '5nrtp09', 3, 3, 8 ]
]
```

Would there be a way to count the number of times the values on the right appear and what 'estimate' ID at [0] it appears in?

Thank you.

Comment: please add a valid data structure. you can not have a key/value as item of an array.

Comment: @NinaScholz Hi, Sorry would be able to example what you mean? Would you be referring to naming the sub-arrays with the estimate IDs? Like
```
[
estimate[ {1: 2} ]
]
```

Comment: `[ { '0': 3 }, { '1': 4 }, { '2': 6 }, -->'Estimate:': '0jvyt8a'<-- ],`

Comment: btw, in what relation is the data to the wanted result?

Comment: @NinaScholz What would be the best way of doing this? I have been trying to name the arrays before but I couldn't get it to work this was instead the comprise of getting it to work and have the information still in that array.

Comment: i have no idea, what you are doing. what is the deeper/real purpose of all?

Comment: @NinaScholz Essentially I need to find out how many times each item in the subarrays a value occurs across the entire array and what sub-arrays that value can be found in. This is purely to process data at the minute as it will be then piped into another application to display the data that is sorted here.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm unable to go into the details of it. But, basically the data is manually recorded and it is easier to record against a central 'estimate number'  but by doing it this way we end up with unique estimate numbers but duplicate values in the sub-arrays, instead I need to transform the arrays so we have unique values with each estimate against that value.

Comment: I can't understand how the output relates to the input, either. You have both `{1: "vwsfh8k"}` and `{3:"vwsfh8k"}`, what do `1:` and `3:` represent? Why are they both in the result?

Comment: An array of objects where each object has different keys is usually poor design. Why not just an array like `["vwsfh8k", "v0jn7bh"]`?

Comment: @Barmar In the sub-arrays, the 1: and 3: are just the index of the value. On the right hand side of the output sub-arrays is 1 and 3. I'm trying to find a way to look through the first array and return the estimate ID for each time that value occurs.

Comment: @Barmar That would work to, to be honest I don't know why I didn't do it that way.

Comment: do you have a better result structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's redesign your input data and results to be a more useful format:

```
// input
[
  { nodes: [3, 4, 6], Estimate: '0jvyt8a' },
  { nodes: [4, 6, 3], Estimate: 'mc973fs' },
  { nodes: [4, 1, 3], Estimate: 'vwsfh8k' },
  { nodes: [4, 3, 5], Estimate: 'n6xzge3' },
  { nodes: [8, 7, 1], Estimate: 'v0jn7bh' }
];
// result
{
  1: ["vwsfh8k", "v0jn7bh"],
  3: ["0jvyt8a", "mc973fs", "vwsfh8k", "n6xzge3"],
  ...
]
```

Then the code would be:

```js
const input = [
  { nodes: [3, 4, 6], Estimate: '0jvyt8a' },
  { nodes: [4, 6, 3], Estimate: 'mc973fs' },
  { nodes: [4, 1, 3], Estimate: 'vwsfh8k' },
  { nodes: [4, 3, 5], Estimate: 'n6xzge3' },
  { nodes: [8, 7, 1], Estimate: 'v0jn7bh' }
];

const result = {};
input.forEach(({
    nodes,
    Estimate: e
  }) =>
  nodes.forEach(n => {
    if (!result[n]) {
      result[n] = [];
    }
    result[n].push(e);
  })
);

console.log(result);
```

You can create the data with:

```js
// Making an empty array
const arr = [];

//Generating the estimate IDs and placing them all in their own object in their own array.
function estimateGen(length, nodes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let estimateVal = Math.random().toString(36).replace('0.', '').slice(0, 7);
    const estimate = {
      Estimate: estimateVal,
      nodes: []
    }
    arr.push(estimate);
    nodeGen(estimate, nodes)
  }
}

// Adding x amount of nodes between 1 and 10 into each estimate sub array in their own objects.
function nodeGen(estimate, nodes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
    let nodeID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    estimate.nodes.push(nodeID);
  }
}

// Calling the function and saying how many nodes per estimate we want.
estimateGen(5, 3);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this works perfectly. Do you know how I could go about editing my code that creates the array to put it into your input format so I can continue experimenting with parameters.

Comment: I've modified your geneation code to produce this format.

Answer (score 0):

I've reformatted your array. The output is different, but you can still use it.

```js
var arr = [
  { '0': 3 ,  '1': 4 ,  '2': 6 , 'Estimate:': '0jvyt8a' },
  { '0': 4 ,  '1': 6 ,  '2': 3 , 'Estimate:': 'mc973fs' },
  { '0': 4 ,  '1': 1 ,  '2': 3 , 'Estimate:': 'vwsfh8k' },
  { '0': 4 ,  '1': 3 ,  '2': 5 , 'Estimate:': 'n6xzge3' },
  { '0': 8 ,  '1': 7 ,  '2': 1 , 'Estimate:': 'v0jn7bh' }
];

var num = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];


num = num.map(n => 
        [n, ...(
        arr.filter(a => [0, 1, 2].some(nm => a[nm] === n))
        .map(v => v["Estimate:"])
        )]);

console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting a counting object you could take the values as key and `estimates` as key for the count of same values.

```js
function estimateGen(length, nodes) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)    {
        array.push([Math.random().toString(36).replace('0.','').slice(0,7), ...nodeGen(nodes)]);            
    }
    return array;
}

function nodeGen(nodes) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
        result.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    }
    return result;
}

function count(data) {
    return data.reduce((r, [estimate, ...values]) => {
        values.forEach(v => {
            r[v] = r[v] || {};
            r[v][estimate] = (r[v][estimate] || 0) + 1;
        });
        return r;
    }, {});
}

var temp = estimateGen(5, 3);

console.log(temp);
console.log(count(temp));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```